# Cannot open database "testdb" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: c#, mysql

I tried to connect to database:

```
string ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;" 
                        + "DATABASE=testdb;" 
                        + "User Id=wsuser;" 
                        + "PASSWORD=12345;" 
                        + "Integrated Security=True;";

SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
Connection.Open();
```

And got error `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Cannot open database "testdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-F9N7UKE\Stolz'."`

In mysql i have user `wsuser` with all previlegies to `testdb` database.
Someone know how fix this exception?

Comment: You seem to be trying to use a MSSql connector. That won't be able to connect to MySQL. You'll need to use an appropriate library, such as https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/

Comment: Arent you using wrong client for MySQL ? SqlConnection is a MS SQL client implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql database connection is like this

```
 string ConnectionString = "SERVER=localhost;" 
                    + "DATABASE=testdb;" 
                    + "User Id=wsuser;" 
                    + "PASSWORD=12345;" 

                     MySqlConnection Connection = new 
                     MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                     Connection.Open();
```

Use MySqlconnection to connect Mysql database and Sqlconnection to connect Sqlserver.